# Customized CSS Style Not Working for ag-grid

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, ag-grid

Seems pretty basic, but the documentation is [scant](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/global-style-customisation/).

Creating a module override CSS, I have tried to customize line-height for one of my tables so that text does not double-space when text wrapping.

Here is the CSS, `Test.module.css`:

```
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-cell, .ag-theme-alpine .ag-full-width-row .ag-cell-wrapper.ag-row-group {
    line-height: min(var(--ag-line-height,20px),20px);
  }
```

Here is a sample of my module, `Test.tsx`:

```
import './Test.module.css'
...
return (
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: '105px', width: screenWidth }}>
          <AgGridReact rowData={testData} columnDefs={testCols} headerHeight={hiddenHeader} getRowHeight={getRowHeight} rowStyle={{width: screenWidth}} ></AgGridReact>
        </div>
)
```

The result? Line-height remains the default (may be hard to see, but there is a second line of text below the first):

[image]

[image]

I have also attempted several variations on the below:

- `.ag-theme-alpine .ag-cell { line-height: min(var(--ag-line-height,20px),20px); }`
- `.ag-theme-alpine .ag-cell { line-height: 20; }`
- `.ag-theme-alpine .ag-cell { --ag-line-height: '20px'; }`
- Adding `!important` to the end of the line, e.g. `.ag-theme-alpine .ag-cell { line-height: 20 !important; }`

Note that the variable name was found in the console, as it does not appear in the list of variable names found in the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/global-style-customisation-variables/). Maybe this is the problem, but I have yet to see a variable that meets the criteria.

Comment: Have you checked what the compiled output is? From your description it sounds you don't actually want a CSS module, but a regular CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this in a bit of an unexpected way. Adding the below to the global style sheet overrode the default:

```
.ag-cell {
  line-height: min(var(--ag-line-height,15px),15px) !important;
}
```

Note that I had to change the class being referenced, paring it back to `.ag-cell` only. Not sure why exactly, but this was the only thing that worked.